# Efficient function selector once at runtime

Tags: c++, function-pointers, mex

I have an operation that I need to perform many times in parallel. For example interpolate an image at a cloud of points. For this operation I have a few variants. For example different interpolation functions (think linear, quadratic, cubic, etc.). The question is, how to efficiently select the operation once during runtime. I want to avoid branching for every call of the operation.

Normally, I would use template instantiation for this. However, I'm calling the function thru the Matlab Mex API. This means, that I don't know the "chosen" operation at compile time.

Now, I was thinking maybe about using function pointers, but I don't have experience using them. What would be an efficient method for selecting one variant of the particular operation such that subsequent calls will be transferred directly to the correct version.

Minimal example:

```
class Image
{
public:
    size_t siz[3] = { 0, 0, 0 }; // image size (always 3D)
    double *f; // input image
    
    Image(double *f, size_t i, size_t j, size_t k) : f(f), siz{i, j, k} {
    }

    double interp_v1(size_t offset) {
    return // insert code to do interpolation method 1
    }

    double interp_v2(size_t offset) {
    return // insert code to do interpolation method 2
    }

    double interp_v3(size_t offset) {
    return // insert code to do interpolation method 3
    }

    double (*interp)(size_t offset) {
    return interp_v1 // use interp_v1 when interp is called (can be changed at runtime)
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for all the great answers, had to pick one but there are multiple ones that helped me understand the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably both options should be roughly the same. If performance is really important, just measure your code. I did a benchmark and ifs were as fast as pointer.

Keep in mind that if you use a function pointer, you have an indirection, and with the "if" statement branching should not be a huge problem, as branch prediction would start to guess right every time (in theory) after some calls. So you should probably just choose the one that feels clearer and easier to understand. In my case, the if statement makes this clearer and probably makes inlining more viable.

Another option that I've tried and seems to be as fast (and in some cases even faster) is dynamic polymorphism. This one is also easier to maintain in case someone wants to add new methods. This an example with dynamic polymorphism.:

```
struct Base {
    void whatever() = 0;
};

struct Method1: Base {
    void whatever() override {
//Code for first method
    }
};

struct Method2: Base {
    void whatever() override {
//COde for second method..
    }
};
```

Here you have the link to my benchmakrs: https://quick-bench.com/q/1mR0EyYrqvzunpEGbrHBw_U7eEY

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your problem correctly, you could choose the operation ahead of time before you enter the part of the code where you call it over and over again.

```
double interp_v1(std::size_t offset)
{
    //implementation here
}

double interp_v2(std::size_t offset)
{
    //implementation here
}

int main()
{
    double (*interp_func)(std::size_t);

    if ( /* some condition */ ) {
        interp_func = interp_v1;
    }
    else if ( /* some other condition */ ) {
        interp_func = interp_v2;
    }

    //Loop that does the heavy lifting
    for (int counter = 0; counter != 1000000; ++counter) {
        auto some_variable = interp_func(offset);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the difference between manual set function pointers vs. virtual functions vs. a small set of switch/case will not differ very much in comparison to the real underlying operation.

If talking about pictures and tons of pixels, you should think about best algorithms and not about the one or two indirections of using function or vtable pointers.

In addition, I expect code size doesn't matter, you can template your loop with the function to call and get really zero run time overhead inside the loop itself, as the member pointer is a compile time constant.

```
class Image
{
    public:
        double *f; // input image
        size_t siz[3] = { 0, 0, 0 }; // image size (always 3D)

        Image(double *f, size_t i, size_t j, size_t k) : f(f), siz{i, j, k} {
        }

        double interp_v1(size_t offset) {
            return 0; // insert code to do interpolation method 1
        }

        double interp_v2(size_t offset) {
            return 0;// insert code to do interpolation method 2
        }

        double interp_v3(size_t offset) {
            return 0;// insert code to do interpolation method 3
        }

        template < auto which_func >
            double loop( size_t offset )
            {
                //Loop that does the heavy lifting
                for (int counter = 0; counter != 1000000; ++counter) {
                    auto some_variable = (this->*which_func)(offset);
                }

                return 0;
            }

};


int main()
{
    double f[3];
    Image img{ f, 1,1,1 };

    int what = 1;

    switch ( what )
    {
        case 0:
            img.loop<&Image::interp_v1>(0);
            break;

        case 1:
            img.loop<&Image::interp_v2>(0);
            break;

        case 0:
            img.loop<&Image::interp_v3>(0);
            break;
    }

}
```

I don't know the full data structures you have. But you maybe also can remove the "this->*" if you have static functions or can modify to static functions. This can avoid dereferencing the this pointer if it is really a problem.

And a hint for all performance issues: Measure, measure, measure. It is often the case that compilers are very good by optimizing things out of the loops. So you may already get the pointer dereferencing stuff already out of the loop without any "compiler hints". I believe your algorithm is much more important and also the memory layout and call order. Cache line misses and such kind of expensive problems are much more important as the single pointer usage!

Comment: It is the “int what = 1” that I cant do, since this information will be coming from the matlab mex call and will not be known at compile. I’m silently hoping I could still use templates, but I haven’t found a way.

Comment: @Jann5s Yes, the what parameter is runtime and the rest is compile time. That is exactly the intention.

Comment: I see now, I'm going to play with your suggestion, thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you are just wanting an example that uses function pointers, here is a method that uses a function pointer array.  The code is set up so that you can change the function pointer in use at run time.

```
double interp_v1(size_t offset) {
return 1;// insert code to do interpolation method 1
}

double interp_v2(size_t offset) {
return 2;// insert code to do interpolation method 2
}

double interp_v3(size_t offset) {
return 3;// insert code to do interpolation method 3
}

// Array of function pointers with the specified signature
double (*interp_array[])(size_t offset) =
{ interp_v1, interp_v2, interp_v3 };

// Function pointer with the specified signature
double (*interp_ptr)(size_t offset) = interp_array[0];

// Set the function pointer
void interp_set(int i) {
    if( i > 0 && i <= sizeof(interp_array)/sizeof(interp_array[0]) ) {
        interp_ptr = interp_array[i-1];
    }
}

// Function interp uses whatever funtion interp_ptr is pointing to
double interp(size_t offset) {
return interp_ptr(offset);
}
```

Comment: I was more curious to the kind of overhead that is involved in such a setup. If I understand the message of various answers well, then the gist is that it will be nonzero but tiny.